# How to export a texture as jpeg or png?

Tags: texturing

I downloaded my Blender model from the Internet, and it already had built-in textures for its materials and meshes.

How can I download the texture as a `.png` or `.jpeg` to edit it?

Comment: I have literally no idea what you are talking about . . .

Comment: I just wanted to know how to save a texture from a Blender project onto my hard drive

Answer (score 7):

If I understand your question, you want to save on your hard drive a texture from a Blender project: open a window as UV image editor window, select the texture from the drop down menu (which contains all the images in the project) and choose "Image - Save as image".

[image]

Comment: Thank you Soo much, you have no idea how much this helped

Answer (score 2):

For those using Blender 2.9, in the UV window, you would go to the *top left* where Image - Save As... would be. You can also press Shift Alt S to quick save in UV editing mode.

[image]

Answer (score -3):

When a model I download has BMP or other files that are PNG for the textures, I use this. I hope it helps you!
https://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-png

Comment: How does this help? The question is about saving textures from within blender to ones computer.